# Set a variable in application controller is good practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a very easy and fast question.
I'm adding to my website header a "trending topics" menu.
The menu is the same for every page, so I need a variable available from every view.

I add this variable in my application controller:

```
before_filter :set_trendings
def set_trendings
    @trendings = Trending.all
end
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a good way of doing that, i don't find any better approach than this.

Comment: You can leave such answers in comment section. This is not an answer actually. :)

Comment: Will remember it from next time :) Thank you